# How to Connect Google Play Real-Time Developer Notifications to Firebase Cloud Function via Pub/Sub?

Tags: firebase, google-play, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-play-console

I'm in the final stages of development for my new mobile app, but can't seem to find a way to allow Google Play Real-Time Developer Notifications to communicate to a firebase cloud function via the recommended Google Pub/Sub method.

The expected payload flow should go as follows:

**User Purchases Subscription via Play Store** > **Play Store sends R-T Dev Notification to Pub/Sub** > **Pub/Sub sends message across to firebase cloud function** > **Cloud function runs with payload**.

I currently have an Apple Developer webhook set-up in a similar way, which webhooks a  receipt payload to an iOS cloud function I have setup.

During the pub/sub setup phase, the Pub/Sub page asks to verify the cloud function URL, which I cannot do as I am not the true webmaster of cloud function domain, hence halting me about halfway down the 'Add real-time developer notification' docs that google supplies.

Is there a way to get the RT notification to either a Pub/Sub cloud function or a HTTPS cloud function bypassing the google Pub/Sub and going directly to the webhook or another way to complete the flow above?

The ultimate aim is to provide a way to ensure the purchase made is actually a valid purchase, and not a forged request made by someone intercepting the client > server webhook and submitting one of their own accord.

Comment: Is there any way of using Google Play Real-Time Developer Notifications but in an AWS Cloud? Like if google can notify my cloud by calling a webhook or my URL that the purchase has been made?

Answer (score 10):

After creating the new topic you **DO NOT** have to create **manually** a Pub/Sub subscription as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications#create_a_pubsub_subscription).

To make it work with firebase you have to deploy a new cloud function like this:

```
exports.YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME = functions.pubsub.topic('YOUR_TOPIC_NAME').onPublish((message) => {

  // Decode the PubSub Message body.
  const messageBody = message.data ? Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString() : null;

  // Print the message in the logs.
  console.log(`Hello ${messageBody || 'World'}!`);
  return null;


});
```

Please note that you need to replace YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME and YOUR_TOPIC_NAME.

When the deploy of this function **finish**, you will finally find the function in the [subscription list](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/subscription/list). 
At this point, you can edit the params of the **automatically** created subscription, and you will find the *url endpoint* **already** filled with an internal url.

Here you can find an example: [how to setup a PubSub triggered Cloud Function using the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/pubsub-helloworld)

Comment: Is there any way of using Google Play Real-Time Developer Notifications but in an AWS Cloud? Like if google can notify my cloud by calling a webhook or my URL that the purchase has been made?